Values reset in engineering mode of AC82271 Android head unit
I have an AC82271 Android head unit on Android 12. I went into engineering mode (by inputting 56789 as the PIN on the factory settings screen) to increase the mic volume, but it just immediately went back to zero even though it says it saved successfully.
Can anyone explain how to save the settings, please?

Please add the device model, Android version, and explain what you mean by "engineering mode"?

Do you mean developer mode by any chance?

Likely a permissions issue?

Hello , I put a pin in at the factory settings screen of 56789 it then allows me to click engineering mode.

I don’t know the make of it as it has nothing but it’s android version 12 and platform ac82271

If the Mic volume is zero I assume it doesn't work? Has the microphone ever worked before? May be this is a "license issue" that the manufacturer want's extra money for the microphone feature?

The microphone has never worked but the external mic came with the radio
